# app must wotking without Internet

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Im trying to run my app without Internet,all good,without errors,but nothing happened.How can I check that data is saved? That saving in doinBackgroung method.Im try to check Internet connection with isNetworkConnected method,if ==true-set adapter to listview,if!=true -set adapter1 to listview.All working with Internet,but without-its just empty listview on my screen.
MainActivity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private Context context;
SqlHelper dbHelper;
    Intent intent;
    private static String url = "https://fierce-citadel-4259.herokuapp.com/hamsters";
    private static final String TITLE = "title";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String IMAGE = "image";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> bdList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
   ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        if(isNetworkConnected()==true) {
            new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
        }
        else {
    displaysavedlv();

        }

ForItemClick();

    }








    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.reload) {
         new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
        }
else if(id == R.id.menu_item_share){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Put whatever you want");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share via"));
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private ListActivity activity;
        private Context context;

        public ProgressTask(MainActivity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
            context = activity;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dbHelper = new SqlHelper(MainActivity.this);
        }

        protected void onPreExecute(){
           this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
           this.dialog.show();
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success){
            try{
       if((this.dialog != null)&& this.dialog.isShowing()){
this.dialog.dismiss();
            }
if(isNetworkConnected()==true) {
    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(MainActivity.this, jsonlist, R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TITLE, DESCRIPTION}, new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.description});
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}else{
    displaysavedlv();
}


        }catch (final IllegalArgumentException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {

           JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            for(int i =0;i<json.length();i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    String vtitle = c.getString(TITLE);
                    String vdescription = c.getString(DESCRIPTION);
                    String vimage = c.getString(IMAGE);
                    dbHelper.open();
dbHelper.createEntry(vtitle,vdescription,vimage);

                    dbHelper.close();
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put(TITLE, vtitle);
                    map.put(DESCRIPTION, vdescription);
map.put(IMAGE, vimage);
                    jsonlist.add(map);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) {
            // There are no active networks.
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }
    public void ForItemClick(){

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String title1 = jsonlist.get(position).get("title");
                String description1 = jsonlist.get(position).get("description");
                String url1 = jsonlist.get(position).get("image");

                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailInfo.class);


                intent.putExtra("title", title1);
                intent.putExtra("description", description1);
                intent.putExtra("url", url1);
                startActivity(intent);


    }
});
    };
    private void displaysavedlv(){
        bdList = dbHelper.getAllData();
lv=(ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        CustomListAdapter adapter1 = new CustomListAdapter(MainActivity.this,bdList,R.id.list_item,new String[]{TITLE,DESCRIPTION},new int[]{R.id.title,R.id.description});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter1);


    }
}
```

SqlHelper:

```
public class SqlHelper {
String title;
    String description;
    String image;
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
private SqlHelper mDb;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBCategory";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "categoryTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    public SqlHelper(Context c){
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public SqlHelper open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();
    }





    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                            KEY_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +KEY_DESCRIPTION +"TEXT NOT NULL ," +KEY_IMAGE + "TEXT NOT NULL );"
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public long createEntry(String title, String description,String image) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        cv.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION,description);
        cv.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllData()
    {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> array_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.ourHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from categoryTable", null );
        res.moveToFirst();

        while(res.isAfterLast() == false){

            HashMap<String,String>  hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashmap.put("title", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(title)));
            hashmap.put("description", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(description)));
            hashmap.put("image", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(image)));


            array_list.add(hashmap);
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where have you been save your data???

Comment: at doInBackgroung-createEntry
CreateEntry in SqlHelper:
 public long createEntry(String title, String description,String image) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        cv.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION,description);
        cv.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

Comment: To check whether your data is saved into database, you can copy and check your sqlite database. If the application is compile as debug, you can use run-as command in adb shell, such that you can access your application's private data.

Comment: Please provide your swlite helper class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isNetworkConnected()==true) {
        new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
    }else {
        new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).onPostExecute(true);

    } Add this code. On only internet connection you are setting adaptor to listview. So on no internet you are doing nothing.
```

Comment: Its not working.
Error 4937-24952/com.example.vnvbnv.myapplication E/JSON PARSER﹕ Error parsing dataorg.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
09-25 09:28:42.135  24937-24952/com.example.vnvbnv.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

I think its try to parsing json,but cant.

Comment: when there is no internet connection else goes directly to onPostExecute so doInBackground() does not run.... include a else and add 
        new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).onPostExecute(true); or 
        new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).onPostExecute(null);

Comment: its not working(
Errors in 4 lines
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  bdList = dbHelper.getAllData();
 at com.example.vnvbnv.myapplication.MainActivity.access$100:
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
  displaysavedlv();
    new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).onPostExecute(null);

Comment: if(isNetworkConnected()==true) {
                    new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
                }else {
                    displaysavedlv();

                } also you can use this in oncreate

Comment: Im trying,but now its NullPointerException in dislplaysavedlv().
bdList=dbHelper.getAlldata();-in this line.

Comment: When there is no internet connect you are missing 
bdList = dbHelper.getAllData(); Add this before instiating adaptor inside displaysavedlv(). Now if you have data in database it should work fine

Comment: Im added this before,before my comment.And still have 2 errors.

Comment: wow,its something new.
17657-17672/com.example.vnvbnv.myapplication E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting image=http://moi-pushistye-druzya.narod.ru/images/00059.jpg title=Случайный хомяк 1 description=Случайное фото случайного хомячка. Он тут — для массовости!
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table categoryTable has no column named image (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO categoryTable(image,title,description) VALUES (?,?,?)

said that I havent image column.But I have.Please,look to SqlHelper,maybe I was wrong?

Comment: Can you update your question both of mainActivity and sqlHelper

Comment: Im added SqlHelper before.

Comment: move this code 
            dbHelper = new SqlHelper(MainActivity.this); from on background to constructor of ProgressTask. and run your app. Try once while there is intenet and again when no intenet. When there is no internet your sqlHelper doesnot get instantiated so no column found error....

Comment: Im added  bdList = dbHelper.getAllData(); to displaysavedlv;
An in this line is NullPointerException.

Comment: Try two things- move 
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list); from ForItemCLick to oncreate. and first run when there is internet fetch some data and turn off the internet and rerun again... If you update your MainActivity in question it will be alot easy..

Comment: move,but nothing happen.Update MainActivity in question.Still have 2 error.How I understand,first caused second.Problem is with
  bdList = dbHelper.getAllData();

Comment: if(isNetworkConnected()==true) {
            new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
        }
        else {
            dbHelper = new SqlHelper(MainActivity.this);
            displaysavedlv();

        } replace with this code in on create... When there is no internet your SqlHelper does not get instantiated and so is null because you are instantiating it inside asyntask which is not called....

Comment: Now its problem with getAlldata()
with
SQLiteDatabase db = this.ourHelper.getReadableDatabase();
this line.

Comment: man i dont see opening your databasehelper replace with this code  public SqlHelper(Context c) {
        ourContext = c;
        open();
    }

Comment: when it started with Internet,its many errors."Table categoryTable has no column named image".Maybe because image have "http://moi-pushistye-druzya.narod.ru/images/00059.jpg" adress like this?

Comment: I dont know what may be the error if you againa update your question and show your errors..... I will try

Comment: @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                            KEY_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +KEY_DESCRIPTION +" TEXT NOT NULL ," +KEY_IMAGE + " TEXT NOT NULL );"
            );
        }  no space after KEY_DESCRIPTION and KEY_IMAGE in your code

Comment: Im updated like this,whats wrong?
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                            KEY_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_IMAGE + " TEXT NOT NULL );"

Comment: in your question there are no spaces between KEY_DESCRIPTION and "TEXT NOT NULL"

Comment: add space but still not working.Maybe I cant save link to sqllite?

Comment: replace in getalldata by
            hashmap.put("title", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_TITLE)));
            hashmap.put("description", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESCRIPTION)));
            hashmap.put("image", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_IMAGE)));
you have unnecessary string name title,description and image delete those on getcolumnindex(invalid string) with above